# Why are my jQuery events not binding properly when in a loop?

Tags: javascript, events, jquery, hotkeys

I am using the jQuery hotkeys plugin to bind some keypresses to events. I tried to change this to bind looping over an array instead, but it's not working.

```
var letters = ["a","b","c"];
for (var x in letters)
{
    var letter = letters[x];
    $("el").bind('keydown', letter, function() { /*...*/  })
           .bind('keyup', letter, function() { /*...*/  });
}
```

This code binds all events to the last letter in the array ("c") and none to others. Is there a better way of doing this ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why would someone bind all of those event listeners? That is some horrible performance there. Yikes.

Comment: Either use a switch statement or an object that contains all of the functions. Add one event handler for keyup and one for keydown. Look up the function in the object or let it be found with the switch case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because JavaScript uses [functional variable scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope).

You want to scope `letter` in its own function:

```
var letters = ["a","b","c"];
letters.forEach(function(letter) {
    $("el").bind('keydown', letter, function() { /*...*/ } })
           .bind('keyup', letter, function() { /*...*/  });
});
```

Yours is basically a minor variation on the [Infamous Loop Problem](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/#highlighter_892783).

See also [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29).

---

Based on your comments (some of which have been deleted?) I suggest the following approach:

```
var events = {
    a: function() {
        console.log("a is for ALPHA");
    },
    b: function() {
        console.log("b is for BRAVO");
    },
    c: function() {
        console.log("c is for CHARLIE");
    }
};
jQuery("#el").keydown(function(e) {
      var ascii = e.keyCode || e.which;
      var handler = events[String.fromCharCode(ascii).toLowerCase()];
      if(handler) {
          handler();
      }
});
```

The jQuery `keydown` event executes for every key which the user presses down on - that second argument you're passing to `bind` doesn't constrain it to only one key.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's working now with just the one event listener ;)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the body of the function is important.  If you are referencing any of your local variables (`x`, `letters`, `letter`, ...) in the function expressions, they "close over" (google closures for more info) the variables and, when the function expression is called to handle the events, they will have a reference to the last value assigned to letter.  For example:

```
var x = "Alice";
var helloAlice = function() { alert("Hello, " + x); };
x = "Bob";
helloAlice(); // Alerts "Hello, Bob"
```

There are a couple of ways to solve this.  One method is to use a self-executing function:

```
var x = "Alice";

var helloAlice = (function(name) {
  return function() { alert("Hello, " + name); };
})(x);

x = "Bob";
helloAlice(); // Alerts "Hello, Alice"
```

Your code, `var letter = letters[x];` does **not** work like this because JavaScript does not support block level scoping, only function level.  This means in your code, `letter` is in the same scope as `letters` (You should also google variable hoisting for more information about this).